# Populates Data from one Workbook to Another

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine

Another code clean up I am working on.  I have been breaking up my code based on things I have learned here on CR.  The code below all works and functions as expected, but I know it can be streamlined more and would like to see how this can be accomplished.  The code below was combined into one code block here for ease of copying, but if I need to break it up into the sheet events and standard modules please let me know.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Send_Click()
    SendToQC
End Sub
Option Explicit
Sub SendToQC()

    Dim cYear As String
    cYear = Year(Now())

    Dim nYear As String
    nYear = cYear + 1

    Dim logWBpath As String
    logWBpath = "L:\Loans\Quality Control\QC Log " & nYear & ".xlsx"

    Dim testStr As String
    testStr = ""

    Dim ret As Boolean
    ret = IsWorkBookOpen(logWBpath)

    Select Case ret
        Case Is = True
            Dim msgCap As String
            msgCap = "The QC Log is currently open.  Please try again later or manually enter the data."

            MsgBox msgCap, vbInformation + vbOKOnly

            Exit Sub
        Case Is = False
            On Error Resume Next
            testStr = Dir(logWBpath)

            On Error GoTo 0

            Dim closeDate As Date
            closeDate = Sheet1.Range("P9")

            Dim logWB As Workbook
            Dim logWS As Worksheet

            Select Case Right(closeDate, 4)
                Case Is = cYear
                    PopulateData logWB, logWS, ThisWorkbook, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("In-House"), cYear
                Case Is = nYear
                    If testStr = "" Then
                    Dim ErrMsg As String
                        ErrMsg = "The QC Log for " & nYear & " may not have been created yet or has a different naming convention." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                                 & "Please Contact Zack Elcombe." & vbCrLf & "      Ext:  4519" & vbCrLf & "      Email:  ZackE@coderules.coderuls"
                        MsgBox ErrMsg, vbCritical
                    Else
                        PopulateData logWB, logWS, ThisWorkbook, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("In-House"), , nYear
                    End If
                Case Is = ""
                    MsgBox "Closing Date is required", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            End Select

            With Sheet1.Send
                .Locked = True
                .Enabled = False
                .BackColor = vbGreen
            End With

    End Select


End Sub
Sub PopulateData(LogWorkbook As Workbook, LogWorksheet As Worksheet, QualityContWB As Workbook, _
                 QualityContWS As Worksheet, Optional ByVal CurrentYear As String, Optional ByVal NextYear As String)


    If Not CurrentYear = "" Then
        Set LogWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("L:\Loans\Quality Control\QC Log " & CurrentYear & ".xlsx", False)
    Else
        Set LogWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("L:\Loans\Quality Control\QC Log " & NextYear & ".xlsx", False)
    End If

    Set LogWorksheet = LogWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set QualityContWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set QualityContWS = QualityContWB.Sheets("In-House")

    Dim dataRow As Long
    dataRow = LogWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    LogWorksheet.Range("B" & dataRow) = Format(QualityContWS.Range("P9"), "General Date")
    Select Case LCase(Split(QualityContWS.Range("lnOfficer"), " ")(0))
        Case Is = "cassie": LogWorksheet.Range("C" & dataRow) = "CLH"
        Case Is = "amy": LogWorksheet.Range("C" & dataRow) = "ASN"
        Case Is = "nancy": LogWorksheet.Range("C" & dataRow) = "NAK"
        Case Is = "liz": LogWorksheet.Range("C" & dataRow) = "EAO"
        Case Is = "rob": LogWorksheet.Range("C" & dataRow) = "RTE"
    End Select
    LogWorksheet.Range("D" & dataRow) = QualityContWS.Range("LnProcessor")
    LogWorksheet.Range("E" & dataRow) = QualityContWS.Range("BorrowerName")
    LogWorksheet.Range("F" & dataRow) = QualityContWS.Range("LnNumber")
    LogWorksheet.Range("G" & dataRow) = "No"

    Dim Reviewer As String

    If Len(QualityContWS.Range("Reviewer")) > 0 Then
        Select Case LCase(Split(QualityContWS.Range("Reviewer"), " ")(0))
            Case Is = "hunter": Reviewer = "HMP"
            Case Is = "cindy": Reviewer = "CKK"
            Case Is = "zack": Reviewer = "ZJE"
            Case Is = "terri": Reviewer = "TJE"
        End Select
    Else: Reviewer = ""
    End If

    Select Case Len(QualityContWS.Range("DateCleartoClose"))
        Case Is = 0
            LogWorksheet.Range("H" & dataRow) = Reviewer
            LogWorksheet.Range("I" & dataRow) = vbNullString
        Case Is > 1: LogWorksheet.Range("I" & dataRow) = QualityContWS.Range("DateCleartoClose")
    End Select

    Dim qcComments As String

    qcComments = QualityContWS.Range("C88") & " " & QualityContWS.Range("C89") & " " & QualityContWS.Range("C90") & " " & QualityContWS.Range("C91")

    LogWorksheet.Range("J" & dataRow) = qcComments & ". " & Reviewer

    LogWorkbook.Save
    LogWorkbook.Close
End Sub
Option Explicit
Function IsWorkBookOpen(filename As String) As Boolean
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: What is `With Sheet1.Send`????

Comment: its an ActiveX button on the worksheet

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Case ret
    Case Is = True

        Exit Sub
    Case Is = False

End Select
```

I would write a `Select Case` that will never have more than two conditions as an `If..Else` statement.

In this case, I prefer to wrap the `IsWorkBookOpen()` in its own `If` statement because you are going to exit the sub if it is triggered.   This will save you an indent level and eliminate the need for the `ret` variable.

```
If IsWorkBookOpen(logWBpath) Then
    Dim msgCap As String
    msgCap = "The QC Log is currently open.  Please try again later or manually enter the data."

    MsgBox msgCap, vbInformation + vbOKOnly

    Exit Sub
End If
```

Adding white-space before and after your code blocks (e.g. If, Select, Sub, Function..) will make the code easier to read.

```
If Len(QualityContWS.Range("Reviewer")) > 0 Then
    Select Case LCase(Split(QualityContWS.Range("Reviewer"), " ")(0))
        Case Is = "hunter": Reviewer = "HMP"
        Case Is = "cindy": Reviewer = "CKK"
        Case Is = "zack": Reviewer = "ZJE"
        Case Is = "terri": Reviewer = "TJE"
    End Select
Else: Reviewer = ""
End If
```

Use with blocks to shorten references:

Before

```
Dim qcComments As String

qcComments = QualityContWS.Range("C88") & " " & QualityContWS.Range("C89") & " " & QualityContWS.Range("C90") & " " & QualityContWS.Range("C91")

LogWorksheet.Range("J" & dataRow) = qcComments & ". " & Reviewer
```

After

```
With QualityContWS

    LogWorksheet.Range("J" & dataRow) = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(" ", True, .Range("C89:C91").Value, ". ", Reviewer)

End With
```

Good thing that these are going to be the only 4 employees who will never leave the company or you may need to rewrite a lot of code in the future.  Normally, I would recommend storing the employee information in a database and writing some lookup functions or an employee information class but I am sure you will be alright.

```
Dim dataRow As Long
dataRow = LogWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

I'm really not a fan of having a lastrow variable unless absolutely necessary.

As I have mentioned in answers to other questions of the OP, consider using Enumeration to reference you columns.

```
Public Enum LogWorksheetColumns
    cA = 1
    cDateOf
    lnOfficerInitials
    cLnProcessor
    cBorrowerName
    cLnNumber
    cYesNo
    cReviewer
    cDateCleartoClose
End Enum

Sub PopulateData(...)
    '...
    Dim newRow As Range

    With LogWorksheet
        Set newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
    End With

    With QualityContWS
        newRow(cDateOf) = Format(.Range("P9"), "General Date")
        newRow(lnOfficerInitials) = GetLnProcessor(Split(QualityContWS.Range("lnOfficer").Value, " ")(0))
        newRow(cLnProcessor) = .Range("LnProcessor").Value
        newRow(cBorrowerName) = .Range("BorrowerName").Value
        newRow(cLnNumber) = .Range("LnNumber").Value
        newRow(cYesNo) = "No"
        newRow(cDateCleartoClose) = ....
    End With

    '...
End Sub
```

`Rows.Count` needs to be qualified to a worksheet:

`LogWorksheet.Cells(LogWorksheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Thanks again for your great breakdown of these items.  Im not familiar with the `enum` statement, but I will definitely research it.  Looks like the laundry list of items when i submit code here is getting shorter and shorter now thanks to you.  Much Appreciated! :)

Comment: @ZackE thanks again for accepting my answer but you may want to wait a couple of days before you accept an answer on a review.  This will give others a chance to post different perspectives.  Multiple reviews are good for everybody, even the reviewers.

Comment: good to know.  I will definitely do that on future questions.